# git segfaults on merge - submodule conflict

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-submodules

I'm trying to combine code on two branches with the 'git merge' command, but git is crashing during the process. I need to find an alternative way to merge these branches.

To increase merge output to a debug level I ran:

```
    $ export GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY=5
```

I am currently on the destination branch. git-status shows everything clean and clear.
When I merge the branches, this is what I see (I've replaced check-in comments with %%%%%% and filenames with ####### as they may be business-sensitive).

```
$ git merge origin/PH-RELEASE-146.0
Merging HEAD with origin/PH-RELEASE-146.0
Merging:
8399d82 %%%%%%
4f9dcfe %%%%%%
found 2 common ancestor(s):
e0a5fa1 %%%%%%
ce62bf1 %%%%%%
  Merging:
  e0a5fa1 %%%%%%
  ce62bf1 %%%%%%
  found 1 common ancestor(s):
  af34a07 %%%%%%
  Skipped ######## (merged same as existing)
  Removed ########
  Removed ########
  ...
  Removed ########
  Auto-merged build
  CONFLICT (submodule): Merge conflict in build - needs b3efae4855bc5eb83aa3167ce6c309a4503c3286
  There are unmerged index entries:
  1 build
  2 build
  3 build
Merge with strategy recursive failed.
```

It turns out that at this point, git-merge has crashed. How do I know this?
 - when running git under Cygwin:

```
$ git merge origin/PH-RELEASE-146.0

     11 [main] git 4352 _cygtls::handle_exceptions: Error while dumping state (probably corrupted stack)

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

- when running git under Linux, with 'ulimit -c unlimited':

```
    $ ulimit -c unlimited; ls -l core; git merge origin/PH-RELEASE-146.0; ls -l core
    ls: cannot access core: No such file or directory
    Merging HEAD with origin/PH-RELEASE-146.0
    ...
    ...
    Merge with strategy recursive failed.
    -rw------- 1 user group 1589248 Jul 29 12:48 core
```

- in both cases, .git/index.lock remains and must be manually deleted before any git command will work again:

  $ git status
  fatal: unable to create '.git/index.lock': File exists

I've manually walked through the merge above by comparing the commit IDs with the ones in the gitk tree. It seems clear to me that git is looking for common ancestors and breaking the merge up into pieces, dealing with each ancestor recursively. But what I think has caused the problem is that the "git-link" to a sub-module called "build" has changed between commits e0a5fa1 and ce62bf1:

- in e0a5fa1 the submodule build is meant to be 8dc84b6
- in ce62bf1 the submodule build is meant to be b3efae4

So obviously there's a conflict. But it's a conflict during the "partial" merge or whatever it's called, not the final one. And git does not seem to handle this very well at all.

Ok, so there's probably a bug - how would I go about submitting a bug report?

But what I'm really concerned about here is the fact that I cannot merge these two branches. Does anybody know an alternative way to bring these branches together without using the 'merge' command? Can I get 'git-merge' to somehow ignore this submodule completely during the entire merge process?

Linux git version 1.6.0.4

Cygwin git version 1.6.1.2

Comment: You could try deleting the submodule from each branch prior to merging, and then add the submodule after the merge.

Comment: I tried that but it unfortunately doesn't work, because git goes back through the commit history to the secondary ancestors, where the submodule exists and cannot be deleted.

I resolved this in the end by cherry-picking the commits from one branch onto the other, but deliberately skipping any commits that updated the submodule.

Comment: Fortunately our sub-modules are always updated without any other changes in the commit! Once I had done this, I was able to use "git merge -s resolve origin/PH-RELEASE-146.0" to bring the two branches together (the only difference in the merge commit was the missing submodule) and then later add the submodule back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading git on linux, 1.6.3.3 is the latest, if that doesn't help try William's idea.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that 1.6.3.3 does not exhibit this issue. The merge correctly identifies a conflict with the submodule, but instead of crashing it properly continues the merge and adds other files to the index.